# Elements are not visible after selecting items from dropdown in android app

Tags: android, ruby, appium, appium-android

There is a city field (drop down) in the address section, after clicking on it a pop up will open in which I can select the city after selecting city I'm not able to select any of the address elements.

```
def selecting state
      puts "Selecting State "
      puts  @utilities.is_element_present("id",get_selector(:address_1)) #returns true
      find_element(id:  get_selector(:province)).click #open dropdown
      sleep 1.5
      find_elements(id: "android:id/text1")[0].click . #select first state 
      sleep 2
      puts  @utilities.is_element_present("id",get_selector(:address_1))
#returns false   
    end
```

Ideally, address1 field should be true even after selecting the state.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37017411) has been there for years and it's up to Google to fix it.

As a workaround you can create a list of object that your dropdown should contain and select item you want with 'down arrow' key. You can then verify what has been picked in textview field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I think I might not be able to convey my point properly. My UIAutomator is working fine it's just that driver is not able to detect address fields after selecting the city from the drop-down (pop-up type) which were detected perfectly by the driver before selecting the city. I've attached screenshots for the reference. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: I would check what Appium actually sees by getting list of all visible elements with xpath "//*".

Comment: I have tried this xpath thing //* but it's not working or taking too much time to execute. One more detail would like to add this page is built in hybrid (react), pop up like these are working fine in the native app, but on this hybrid page, it is creating difficulties.

Comment: That xpath should always work :/ so, you're saying the page from your screenshots is webview?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Appium. As a workaround,
after closing the popup/dialog, if we put the app in background and resume it  . i.e. clicking home button and opening the app again from recent apps, Appium will start detecting the elements again.

Comment: Seems weird but I too experienced the same issue and this worked like a charm. Thanks Shrirang :)